# Why does every $ m \times n$ matrix of rank $r$ reduce to $(m \times r)$ times $(r \times n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

How can I prove the following statement?

> Every $m \times n$ matrix of rank $r$ reduces to $(m \times r)$ times $(r \times n)$:
>
> $A = $ (pivot columns of $A$) (first $r$ rows of $R$) = (COL)(ROW).

<sub>[ Source: Gilbert Strang, *Introduction to Linear Algebra*, question $56$, section $3.2$. ]</sub>

I think that the $R$ is reduced row echelon form. I believe there is a brief elegant proof.

Comment: How do you define the rank of a matrix?

Comment: @Brian The dimension of column space.

Answer (score 3):

Let $m\times n$ matrix $A=\left[a_1, \ldots, a_r, a_{r+1},\ldots,a_n\right]$, without loss of generality (I guess you can switch the columns), let first $r$ columns are its pivot columns, denote as $P$, and the left $n-r$ columns are free columns, denote as $F$.

Its reduced echelon matrix $R=\left[\begin{array}{c c}
I_{r\times r}&F^0_{r\times(n-r)} \\
0_{(m-r)\times r}& 0_{(m-r)\times (n-r)}
\end{array}\right] $.

Since $R$ is derived from row eliminations, it’s equivalent to left multiply a series of elementary matrices, which are $m\times m$ and invertible.

So we have

$A=ER$, $E$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix.

Rewrite the equation above as
$[P,F] = E\left[\begin{array}{c c}
I & F^0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$,

so, $P=E\left[\begin{array}{c}
I\\
0\end{array}\right],F=E\left[\begin{array}{c}
F^0\\
0\end{array}\right]$.

We want to prove $A=P[I,F^0]$, that is, $A$ equals the pivot columns of $A$ times of first $r$ rows of $R$.

Since $P[I,F^0]=[PI,PF^0]=[P, PF^0]$, the first $r$ columns are pivot columns themselves. left we want to show $PF^0=F$, the free columns.

Since $P=E\left[\begin{array}{c}
I\\
0\end{array}\right]$, then

$PF^0 = E\left[\begin{array}{c}
I\\
0\end{array}\right]F^0=E\left[\begin{array}{c}
F^0\\
0\end{array}\right]=F$. It's indeed the free columns. Proved.

Comment: I was looking for a proof where you start from the actual process of row reduction and end up proving that the original matrix can indeed be expressed as the product of the pivot columns, and the non-zero rows of the echelon matrix. Your proof does exactly that. Thanks for giving a clear and an air-tight proof of this important result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{v_1,\dotsc, v_r\}$ be a basis of $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ where $A$ is $m\times n$.  Put these basis vectors into the columns of a matrix $V$, so that
$$
V=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}v_1 & \cdots & v_r\end{array}\right]
$$
Then, for every $b\in\operatorname{Col}(A)$ there exists a $x_b\in\Bbb R^r$ such that $Vx_b=b$.

Now, let $\{a_1,\dotsc, a_n\}$ be the columns of $A$ so that
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}a_1 & \cdots & a_r\end{array}\right]
$$
Each column $a_k$ of $A$ is in $\operatorname{Col}(A)$. So, let
$$
W=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_{a_1} & \cdots & x_{a_r}\end{array}\right]
$$
What happens when we compute $VW$?

Comment: How shall we connect  with reduced row echelon form  please? @Brain

Comment: The connection is row operations does not change the dependency of columns. In other words, for any $x$ such that $Ax=0$, we have $Rx=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mathbf{A}=[\mathbf{p_1}, \mathbf{f_2}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n}]$ where $\mathbf{p_i}$ is the column of $\mathbf{A}$ indexed $i$ and it is pivot column; while $\mathbf{f_i}$ is free column with similar notation. Therefore, $\mathbf{L}=[\mathbf{p_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n}]$ have columns of pivot columns of $\mathbf{A}$. Let $\mathbf{R}=[\mathbf{p_1^R}, \mathbf{f_2^R}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n^R}]$ be the reduced row echelon form of $\mathbf{A}$. $\mathbf{R^c}$ be the first $r$ rows of $\mathbf{R}$.

Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is of $m$ by $n$ with rank $r$. Because $\mathbf{R}$ is $rref(\mathbf{A})$, the last $r$ rows of $R$ are null row vectors. Thus, $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{R^c}=[\mathbf{p_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n}, \mathbf{f_2}, \cdots]\mathbf{R}$ where the last $n-r$ columns of $[\mathbf{p_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n}, \mathbf{f_2}, \cdots]$ are free columns and first $n$ columns are pivot columns.

Now we need to prove $\mathbf{A}=[\mathbf{p_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n}, \mathbf{f_2}, \cdots]R$. Every entry of $\mathbf{p_i^R}$ is 0 except 1 at the $i^{th}$ row, $[\mathbf{p_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n}, \mathbf{f_2}, \cdots] \mathbf{p_i^R} = \mathbf{p_i}$. The pivot columns of $\mathbf{A}$ remain. For $\mathbf{f_j^R}=[c_0, \cdots, c_n, 0, \cdots]^{T}$, we have $c_0\mathbf{p_0^R}+\cdots+c_n\mathbf{p_n^R}=\mathbf{f_j^R}$. Because $\mathbf{R}$ has the same row space and nullspace of $\mathbf{A}$, $c_0\mathbf{p_0}+\cdots+c_n\mathbf{p_n}=\mathbf{f_j}$, i.e. $[\mathbf{p_1}, \cdots, \mathbf{p_n}, \mathbf{f_2}, \cdots]\mathbf{f_j^R}=\mathbf{f_j}$.

---

Welcome to alternative proofs.

Answer (score 0):

I provide a similar proof as that by Brian.

Denote R as the Reduced Row Echelon Form of A, and E as the matrix that stands for the row operations (i.e. left multiplication) on A that produces A, then we have $EA=R$.

Further notice that the selection of pivotal columns can be expressed as a right multiplication on A, denoted by a n-by-r matrix $J$,

while the slection of the fisrt r rows of R can be expressed as a left multiplication on R, denoted by a r-by-m matrix $K=\begin{bmatrix}I_{r,r} \;\;O_{r,(n-r)}\end{bmatrix}$,

What we are interested to show is

$\begin{align}
AJKR&=A\\
\Leftarrow EAJKR &=EA=R(\text{because E is invertible}) \\
\Leftarrow RJKR &=R
\end{align}$

And it is not too hard to see the last equation hold true, as each pivotal column of R has only one non-zero element, and the left multiplication of an m-by-r matrix $RJ$ can be considered as appending (m-r) rows of zeros into a r-rows matrix.:

$RJ=\begin{bmatrix}I_{r,r}\\ O_{(m-r),r}\end{bmatrix}$,

We have $RJK=\begin{bmatrix}I_{r,r} \;\;O_{r,(n-r)}\\
O_{(m-r),r}\;O_{(m-r),(n-r)}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}K\\O_{(m-r),n}\end{bmatrix}$, which selects the first r rows while eliminating the rest (m-r) rows to be zeros.

Lastly, $RJKR=\begin{bmatrix}R_{(r,n)}\\O_{(m-r),n}\end{bmatrix}=R$ because the last (m-r) rows of R is zero by itself.